# MYSQL WHEN CASE THEN do nothing

Tags: mysql

What I'm trying to do is set some fields in a very simple 3 column database that I'm using to manage some checkboxes.

I want to set col_2 to 1 if id is in the list, leaving col_3 state untouched.  But if id is not in the list the set col_2 and col_3 to 0.

This is what I have so far, it doesn't work as it gives me some warnings and changed the value of col_3:

```
UPDATE t 
SET col_2 =
 CASE         
    WHEN id IN (list) THEN 1
    WHEN id NOT IN (list) THEN  0
 END,
col_3 = 
 CASE
    WHEN id NOT IN (list) THEN 0
 END
WHERE id IS NOT NULL;
```

Any help appreciated  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how to leave col_3 untouched

```
UPDATE t 
SET col_2 =
 CASE         
    WHEN id IN (list) THEN 1
    WHEN id NOT IN (list) THEN  0
 END,
col_3 = 
 CASE
    WHEN id NOT IN (list) THEN 0
    ELSE col_3 --this
 END
WHERE id IS NOT NULL;
```

As for your warnings, we don't have enough information

Comment: So simple!! I tried "ELSE col_3=col_3" at one point but that set the field to 1 and now I see my error in that.. The warning have gone now you've shown me the correct query.  Many Thanks for you help  :)

Comment: @xgstr: FYI, `ELSE col_3=col_3` is an implied boolean expression. col_3 always equals col_3 -> true -> 1. Think of `IF (col_3==col_3) THEN...`

Answer (score 2):

To handle situations where no value is matched by any WHEN clause, use an ELSE containing an empty BEGIN ... END block, as shown in this example. (The indentation used here in the ELSE clause is for purposes of clarity only, and is not otherwise significant.)

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE PROCEDURE p()
  BEGIN
    DECLARE v INT DEFAULT 1;

    CASE v
      WHEN 2 THEN SELECT v;
      WHEN 3 THEN SELECT 0;
      ELSE
        BEGIN 
           -- simply put this BEGIN and END for the "do nothing" on ELSE
        END;
    END CASE;
  END;
```